# Any benefits of using SnapshotStateList<T> over State<List<T> in terms of recomposition?

Tags: list, performance, android-jetpack-compose, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines

In jetpack compose,
We can convert `MutableStateFlow<T>` to `State<T>` using `collectAsState()` and with delegation `by` can directly assign `T` to the variable.

Now as I understand, it doesn't matter much if I used `MutableState<T>` or `MutableStateFlow<T>` to hold the state, performance-wise.
But for List types however, it seems there is no special version of Flow, ie, if you really need, you can `Flow<List<T>`, which I've seen used most of the time. Then, if you apply `collectAsState()` on `Flow<List<T>`, you get `State<List<T>`.

Now, if I understand correctly, even if a single value was changed (added, removed, modified) in the list the whole list state would be considered new thus *all* respective list item UI components would be recomposed. While with `SnapshotStateList<T>`, *only* the respective element UI will be (re)composed. **Or**, Jetpack compose has some internal optimization for `State<List<T>` that prevents these types of useless recomposition and I should not worry about it.

Comment: `List<T>` is immutable so if a single value was changed means there is a new `List` object. There is no internal optimization, use `SnapshotStateList<T>` to get 'optimized' behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my tests, LazyColumn will **NOT** recompose items as long as you provide the key, even if the it's from `State<List<T>`.

My test sample:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestSampleTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val vm: SimpleViewModel = viewModel()
                    val list by vm.list.collectAsState()
                    SimplePage(
                        list = list,
                        onClick = {
                            vm.add()
                            vm.shuffle()
                        },
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SimplePage(
    list: List<Int>,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
        ) {
            items(
                list,
                key = { it }
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement(),
                    text = it.toString()
                )
            }
        }
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
        }
    }

}

class SimpleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    //    val list = MutableStateFlow(listOf(1, 5, 8, 3, 7, 6))
    val list = MutableStateFlow(listOf(0))

    fun shuffle() = list.update {
        it.toMutableList().apply {
            shuffle()
        }
    }

    fun add() = list.update {
        it.toMutableList().apply {
            add(max() + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `Modifier.animateItemPlacement()` only works when you ensure unique `key` other than positional. And `key` itself ensures no recomposition for the same item. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70596559/13519865

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794279/13519865

Finally, `animateItemPlacement` works, thus key used nicely.

So, we can safely assume that we can use `State<List<T>` for it's Flow operation benefits without thinking much about recomposition cost.

Comment: I'm still open for test based or documentation backed `Right` answers, so feel free to provide one if you have something to offer.